# Generate Price Data from 3 variables and data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, generator, data-science

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that would generate price based on 3 variables. I have to come up with a way from extracting this from some data.

For instance, I'm trying to come up with the price for a used car. The 3 variables would be:

- The make of the car (i.e. Honda Civic)
- The year of the car (i.e. 2006)
- Kilometer's Driven (i.e. 200,000 KM)

I would feed it data extracted from a listing site. The data I would have is the same as above as well as the listing price.

The user can then pick the make, year, and kilometers driven and it will generate an average price based on that data.

Any ideas at all would be helpful! I'm creating this on PHP with an MySQL database.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Any book about Machine Learning would do. This is basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for something simple and that is just based on the available data just using SQL will suffice. You need to GROUP BY, use AVG and filter with WHERE.

If you are looking for something fancier and are looking to make predictions based on limited data or incomplete queries, you should have a look at things like regressions trees.

Comment: Thanks for the regression trees tip. Any idea where I can start?

Comment: If you are into python there is an example for houses here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/s3.amazonaws.com/datarobotblog/notebooks/gbm-tutorial.ipynb